# How to run an ASP.NET web application without VS2010?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, web-applications

Say, I have an ASP.NET web application that I can run in a web browser by opening that solution in VS 2010 and then by going to Debug -> Start without debugging, or by pressing Ctrl+F5.

I was wondering if it's possible to create a link on my desktop to run the same web app but without starting VS2010 first? (Say, by just double-clicking such link.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create a windows batch file to start the `ASP.NET Web Development Server` and point it to your application's root directory.

Here's my .bat file:

```
"C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\DevServer\10.0\WebDev.WebServer40.exe" /path:"E:\NITIN" /vpath:"/MyApp" /port:2510
```

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/166319/Run-ASP-NET-Web-Application-from-Command-Prompt

http://www.dotnetperls.com/development-server-bat

Comment: Thank you. This is what I wanted. The last link explains it pretty well. Any idea how to also start if in a browser from a batch file?

Comment: added code from my bat file.. You access the app by pointing your browser to `http://localhost:2510/MyApp/`

Answer (score 6):

Yes, deploy the site to your `local IIS`

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/32210/Deployment-of-a-Website-on-IIS

http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/33e0a51a-5f8a-40f2-9923-cdd604e1a812.mspx?mfr=true

Comment: I don't have access to IIS. What I meant is they way how VS2010 environment does it.

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28693/Deploying-ASP-NET-Websites-on-IIS-7-0) is a great article describing how to set up your ASP.NET website in IIS. Thus letting it run outside of the visual studio development environment.

Answer (score 0):

You can either upload the website to a hosting server so that the site is accessible from the internet, or you can setup IIS on your development machine and deploy your site to that.

Here is an [msdn article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178477.aspx) with various links on how to go about doing this.

Answer (score 0):

You Want to Run Asp.net Web Site Then U Need To Install IIS 6.0 or Higher in Your Machine..
And want to more guide then Check Out This Link..

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aFVcX5W0VEQ